# Can I actively renounce roles given to me?

Tags: oracle, role, oracle-19c

I am a database developer. Over the many years working in the same company I have been granted many database roles. Many more than I should actually have.

I know I could make a list of the roles I don't need anymore, could send the list to my DBA and they would write a small script to revoke all these roles from my user account.

I would prefer, though, just to renounce the roles given to me, myself. Is this possible in Oracle?

Comment: In general, no.  You could disable a set of roles within a session.  You could set that up as part of your login script but that doesn't seem sensible.  If you have permission to grant and revoke privileges, you could do it but I would doubt a non-DBA would be given that.  Realistically, even if you could, it's good for the DBAs to have that request so they can look at the processes that are in place for transfers to make sure database permissions are changed appropriately.

Comment: @Justin Cave: Thank you. I supposed so, but wanted to save my DBA some work :-)